# Postgresql: Extract text starting from number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `os` which contains below data

```
id         name
--         ----
1          windows server 2012 R2
2          windows 2016 SQL
3          Oracle linux 7.5
```

I need to extract `2012 R2` from `windows server 2012 R2` and `2016 SQL` from `windows 2016 SQL` and `7.5` from `Oracle linux 7.5`

I tried below query but it returns only the number like `2012` and `2016` and `7`

```
SELECT name, substring(name FROM '[0-9]+') FROM os;
```

> For eg How can I extract `2012 R2` from `windows server 2012 R2` using
>   postgresql query?

Comment: What if it has strings like `7.5.1` or  `2012 Release 2`  etc?

Comment: I need to extract 7.5.1 and 2012 Release 2 as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `SELECT name, substring(name FROM '[0-9]+.*') FROM os;`